# fingers and hand deformation

Tags: modeling, rigging, weight-painting, vertex-groups

i was doing a hand with bones in the fingers. but when it's done, the fingers doesn't work properly. i don't know why, but i tried searching on internet and nothing helps. when i rotate the bone of any finger, it makes a strange deformation. i tried painting the weights, tried fixing it with vertex group assign and remove, and make loop cuts in the mesh, but it doesn't work. [image]

Comment: Hello, have you put the Armature modifier above the Subdivision Surface? Also enable the Preserve Volume option of the Armature even though it's not the problem here. You can share your file here: https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: Definitely looks like incorrect weights. One of your finger bones influences the top of the hand. What do you mean by "*i tried painting the weights*"? Have you checked each bone weights in those effected areas? Have you enabled auto-normalize, or manually checked your weights normalization when editing the weights?

Comment: it's done, im changing the values in the menu of vertex weight.

Comment: have you fixed your problem? If not, please share your file